# Does AWS charge for RDS Instance Startup Time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an app that starts and stops an RDS instance on-demand. I understand how AWS charges for a stopped RDS instance.

Does AWS charge for startup/shutdown compute time?

Comment: My intention was to spin up an RDS instance once per hour for about 10 minutes. Thanks to the answer, I now see that the result of doing so would be that I would pay for the full hour and have to wait for startup, for the same price as leaving the instance running 24/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pricing documentation for RDS indicates:

> Pricing is ... from the time a DB instance
>   is launched until it is stopped or deleted.

For [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/aws-rds-per-second-billing/), more specifically:

> RDS is billed in one-second increments for database instances and
>   attached storage. Pricing is still listed on a per-hour basis, but
>   bills are now calculated down to the second and show usage in decimal
>   form. There is a 10 minute minimum charge when an instance is created,
>   restored or started.

FYI, for [regular EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html):

> Each time you start a stopped instance we charge a minimum of one
>   minute for usage. After one minute, we charge only for the seconds you
>   use.

Comment: Plus 1 for the uptodate link

Answer (score 0):

The most cost efficient solution would be to use aurora serverless. This way you dont have to start and stop the instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html

When you use Aurora Serverless, you pay for only the database resources that you consume, on a per-second basis.

Comment: I did this experiment a few months ago and found that Aurora priced out at about $40/mo for a DB with almost nothing in it. The calculator (https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) estimates a basic Aurora at $89/mo. I think either EC2 or RDS is cheaper for on-demand DB.